The problem is that I want to save co-ordinates in firebase realtime database
My problem is I am storing users live location in database but it is getting stored in
"lat/lng: (37.4219983,-122.084)" this format and I want to store co-ordinates only like (37.4219983,-122.084). How can I do that I am using Android with java.
This is my code snippet for taking location
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Current Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
                latlang = userLocation.toString();
            }
        }
    };
    fetchUserLocation();

I don't know how to remove the prefix "lat/lng:".

It's unclear in the above code what value you are saving to your Firebase RTDB. It's also not clear which LatLng class you are using, but you might be able to trim off "lat/lng: " using userLocation.toString().substring(9) to remove the first 9 characters.

I guess you're reading the location elsewhere? Because in this code you already have the latitude and longitude (location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude()). Can you please update the question providing more context?

Please edit your question and show us in a screenshot how exactly the lat and lng are saved now and how exactly would you like to be saved. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Thankyou everyone for the help!!! I solved the issue with this simple line of code                     "String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "(%.7f,%.7f)", userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude);" Thank you for your quick responses

It looks like your are storing the lat/lng as a string "(32,-122)". There is a good chance that you want to search/load markers which only belong into a bounding box later on. For that reason do I advice you to use two properties. Lat and Lng.
Later on, it's possible to use that for search (bbox): eg.: lng < 40 and lng > 34

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
